# Twisted mesh - mobius stripe in Geometry Nodes

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I'm working on a blender project to realize minimal surfaces with Geometry Nodes. Many mathematical formulas and everything is working fine. But in some cases the result mesh is turned or "twisted" like on the picture. Without Geometry Nodes it’s easy to delete the twisted faces and bridge or loft new ones, but I would like to find an automated way to do it straight with Geometry Nodes. Does somebody know if there is a way or maybe a Node combination to solve this issue? I know it's not really probable - but at least it's worth to try it..

[image: Geometry]

[image]

Comment: is this only for a case with a mobius stip, or with other cases? (btw, showing node would be nice). anyway, you could use a grid (instead of a curve) then solidify in both directions, or see if you are rotating only 180° instead of 360° and then do the loft in gn.

Comment: Hi & thx. I could not upload the file yesterday, so here now the blend file to see the Problem more detailed. -  I already use a Grid and also a solidify modifier. In fact the solidifier cause this Problem or at least make it visible. I will try to rotate twice with seperate PI that could be a way :)

Comment: Hi shmuel3, i tired it with splitting 180 degree in both direction instead of 360 only in one, but than the problem appears on the other end :(

Comment: not what I meant, but it looks like you figured it out already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the *Subdivision* and *Merge By Distance* Nodes and set Solidify Modifier's *Mode* to *Complex*.

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks for your tip. I can´t use the subdivision outside the GN. But never the less, switching "Subdivision Node" <> "Merge by Distance Node" plus changing the Solidify Modifier to 0 like you recommend & going on "Complex" in the Modifier solves the Problem to 99,9%. The Geometry is perfect and it stay´s only a tiny "dis-orientation" of the Mesh :) thx a lot

Comment: yeah you are right we just had to swap the nodes and then set to complex. i updated the answer just in case someone needs to know.